# How to compare time based on current time and given time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I'm having confusion for comparing timing

```
current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%I:%M%p")  # current_time ="12:00PM"

given_time ="01:00PM"

if given_time <= current_time:
   print(True)
```

but I don't know is it compare AM/PM so any one help me to compare these timings based on AM/PM.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of comparing the strings representing times, it may be simpler to compare `datetime.time` objects.
You can get one from `datetime.datetime.now()` by calling the `.time()` method. You may need to specify a timezone to get your local time.
As for the `given_time,` you may use `.strptime()` to convert/parse your string to a `datetime` object and then use again its `.time()` method.

```
import datetime


local_timezone = datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(hours=+2))  # adjust to your local timezone if needed
current_time = datetime.datetime.now().astimezone(local_timezone).time()
print(current_time)
# 10:14:35.905299
given_time = datetime.datetime.strptime("01:00PM", "%I:%M%p").time()
print(given_time)
# 13:00:00

print(given_time <= current_time)
# False
```

If timezone adjustment is not needed the `astimezone()` call can be omitted (as well as defining a `local_timezone` of course).

Answer (score -1):

Split in different tasks the same way you compare time.

```py
from datetime import datetime

current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%I:%M%p")  # current_time ="12:00PM"

given_time ="01:00PM"

if given_time[5:7] == 'AM' and current_time == 'PM':
    print(True)
elif given_time[5:7] == 'PM' and current_time == 'AM':
    print(False)
else: # same part of day
    if int(given_time[0:2]) < int(current_time[0:2]): # compare Hour
        print(True)
    elif int(given_time[0:2]) > int(current_time[0:2]):
        print(False)
    else:
        if int(given_time[3:5]) < int(current_time[3:5]): # compare Minute
            print(True)
        elif int(given_time[3:5]) > int(current_time[3:5]):
            print(False)
        else:
            print("Times are the same")
```